# How to Assign Custom Types to Material UI TextField MenuItem Values in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, menuitem, react-typescript

I have a type conflict in my code, and I'm not sure if a simple casting could solve my problem or if there is something fundamentally wrong with my code.

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

interface Store {
  storeId: string;
  storeName: string;
}

const mockApi: Store[] = [
  {
    storeId: "1",
    storeName: "Store 1"
  },
  {
    storeId: "2",
    storeName: "Store 2"
  },
  {
    storeId: "3",
    storeName: "Store 3"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedStore, setSelectedStore] = React.useState<Store>();
  const [stores, setStores] = React.useState<Store[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSelectedStore(event.target.value); // Type conflict here string not a Store
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setStores(mockApi);
    setSelectedStore(mockApi[1]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-select-currency"
        select
        label="Store"
        value={selectedStore}
        onChange={handleChange}
        size="small"
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        fullWidth
      >
        {stores &&
          stores.map((store) => (
            <MenuItem key={store.storeId} value={store}> // type conflict here Store is not a string
              {store.storeName}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </TextField>
      {selectedStore && <div>Store name: {selectedStore.storeName}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I got the same code working in JS in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-chebyshev-cgbco?file=/src/App.js:1133-1170)

And here is my code (not working) in TS in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-sky-cpybp?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1335)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the entire store object as the value just use `store.storeId`. You will also need to change the value prop of the text field to `selectedStore.storeId`.

see: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-fire-irpjz

Comment: I like the solution, but when I do that it takes me back to a previous problem, on page load the initial value that is set, isn't shown in the TextField until it gets selected again.

Comment: @SamuelZrna Try calling `setSelectedStore` before `setStores` in your useEffect

Comment: I'm afraid the same results: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-sea-x0e3v?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Ok I see the problem. It's because initially there is no selectedStore so React renders the TextField asuncontrolled but then you add a selectedStore so you change to a controlled component and React doesn't like this change. You can get around this by passing an empty object to the value of the text field if no selectedStore exists. I've updated my answer with a working version of the code snippet